# Invalid SQL Server Connection String on Linux Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linux, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Linux more specifically Xubuntu. I have installed SQL Server Express on my machine. I'm currently in the making of a web app and my connection does not seem working or I don't understand everything quite right?

The output I get is :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
```

I have already tried what every I could possibly find and nothing worked. It may be because of the lack of information for Linux users but still, I could not figure it out.

In general, I'm trying to connect to my local SQL server using the connection string in my console app using EF core. Like so:

```
internal const string CONNECTION_STRING =
            "Server = .\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Questionnaires; Integrated Security = True";
```

That is the connection string I'm using and should work.

I'm using this command to apply migrations and create the database on my SQL Server:

```
dotnet ef database update 0 --project Data --startup-project WebInterface
```

The full error message I get when I execute the command is as follows:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.3-servicing-35854 initialized 'QuestionnaireDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Migrations MigrationsHistoryTable=Migrations 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Success
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(String browserHostName, String instanceName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle(DataSource details, Int64 timerExpire, Object callbackObject, Boolean parallel)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
```

The result I should get is actually applying all migrations and creating the database.

Comment: Linux doesn't have the same concept of named pipes as windows does. Try using an IP rather than a named pipe. Also Linux doesn't know anything about integrated security

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux has different concept of named pipes. `.\\SQLSERVER` is a [named pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipes) notation.

Also integrated security won't work on Linux (at least w/o setup, Kerberos Authentication is supported though), because its related to Active Directory / NTML Authorization.

So use the regular Standard user name authorization connection string:

```
Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: You made sure the server is actually running locally and listening to the default port?

Comment: You were absolutely right. I have been editing the wrong file for the connection string. Thank you for the help.

Comment: There is no need to define the port?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Server = LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS
```

instead of:

```
Server = .\\SQLEXPRESS
```

This would be because server names use `localhost` as the current server whereas file paths use `.` as a reference the current folder.

If that doesn't work, ensure the SQL Server instance is running. This has tripped me up many times.

Comment: Server part of the connection string isn't about folders, its about hosts or ip where the server is located, or on windows a named pipe (for inter-process communication)

Comment: @Tseng Yes, but from the question, I assumed they were mixing up folders and server names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not provided a fully qualified name for the database server.

write the following query on your SQL server, and retrieve the instance name

```
SELECT @@servername
```

Comment: Used the query and found the server name but even with it i got the same error.