# Docker container can't connect to SQL Server on a remote server

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I have a container hosted ASP.NET Core application but it can't connect to SQL Server on a remote server.

The error is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

This is what I already checked:

- Try to disable firewall on host machine and DB server. : still get the error
- Edit connection string to use IP and port : still get the error
- Ping from application container to DB server: I can ping to DB server normally
- Connect to database server via SQL Server Management Studio: I can connect normally

So I think that the container can see the DB server but can't connect. What's the other thing should I check?

Thank you very much for your help.

**Update**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 1433

#our sql server was use this port for connect
EXPOSE 64608

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY Web.API.sln ./
COPY MyProject.Core/*.csproj ./MyProject.Core/
COPY MyProject.API/*.csproj ./MyProject.API/

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/MyProject.API
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.API.dll"]
```

**Run Docker Command:**

```
docker build -t myproject-api:latest .

docker run -d -p 7991:80 --name myproject-api myproject-api:latest
```

**Connection String:**

```
"data source=172.16.0.88\\SQL_DEV,64608; initial catalog=MyProject; persist security info=True; user id=myuser; password=mypassword;"
```

Comment: Assuming the remote SQL Server is a default instance listening on port 1433, check remote port connectivity from inside the container with `powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('your-database-server', 1433)) 'success'`

Comment: Post the Docker files and the command you used to run the containers.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for suggestion. I'm quite new for Docker. I will try it after I find out how to run powershell command in my container.

Comment: @Max I've updated docker file and command on post. Thank you.

Comment: @LLF try removing all the `EXPOSE 1433, 
EXPOSE 64608`. these are not needed. Can you provide the settings, how are you creating the connection string?

Comment: @prisar, thanks for your reply. I've updated my connection string on the post.

and EXPOSE is something I add to try after I found that my container can't connect to SQL server.

I also try to remove it but it didn't help.

Comment: You have probably checked this already, but just in case: The container will try to connect using tcp/ip so make sure that the  sql server configuration manager shows tcp/ip as enabled and that the TCP/ip properties shows it as listening on all ip addresses (‘listen all’ is set to yes)

Comment: @camba1 I already check it. "Listen all is set to Yes" and "IP All dynamic port is 64608"

Comment: @DanGuzman I don't know how to use powershell from container. So I write some function in my aspnet core like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837541/check-if-a-port-is-open

and I found that it can show the port is open.

I still confuse that it can see db server and can connect to the port but why it can't connect.

Comment: @LLF how did you check for tcp/ip settings for the sql server instance running as container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most probably because of the connection string.

Change your connection string to something like below

```
Server=172.16.0.88\\SQL_DEV,64608;Database=MyProject;UserId=myuser;Password=mypassword
```

or

```
Server=172.16.0.88,64608;Database=MyProject;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword
```

Which ever works.

Comment: This is my connection string. Is there any thing strange?


"data source=172.16.0.88\\SQL_DEV,64608; initial catalog=MyProject; persist security info=True; user id=myuser; password=mypassword;"

Comment: remove `persist security info`

Comment: are you able to connect in debugging mode in visual studio

Comment: It work perfectly fine on vs. or deploy it directly on iis. And did you just remove instance name in your edit?

Comment: i am not so sure about instance name. try both with instance name and then wothout it. copy from my answer and just replace them with your db name userid and password

Comment: Linux or windows container ? If linux connect to the container and check with VIM if the appsettings.config has the correct line ending. Within the code try to write down to a file the connectionString before connecting.

Comment: @prisar already try to edit connectionstring but it didn't work either vs or docker.
I think it because my database was in SQL_DEV instance.

Comment: @prisar Thank you very much for your help. Finally I found that you entirely correct after try to add instance on your connection string. It seem aspnetcore that run on linux container need to use  different connection string format. for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454878/invalid-sql-server-connection-string-on-linux-entity-framework-core

Comment: @LLF what was your final connection string? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem and I changed my Dockerfile image

I replace It

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
```

with this line

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
```

Now It works !

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that seemed to work for me is to put the sql server container and the .net container in the same docker network

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/302#issuecomment-361439294

Comment: This is a workaround. The problem here is that the two system are indipendent and part of two different networks and level of isolations.